# how to convert list items into respective dict in python/mongodb/elementTree

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, elementtree

i am new to python. Now its Python 2.7

I am processing xml in elementTree and using Mongodb. 
XML i am going to process is "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/usgaap.rss.xml"
below is code for that:

```
import os
import cgi
import sqlite3 as litefire
import sys
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from pymongo import Connection
connc2=Connection('localhost',27017)
db2=connc2['rss']
rss=db2.rss

xmlrss=[]
treexsdr = ElementTree.parse('xbrlrss_all.xml')
i=0
k=0
o=0
o2=0
iter = treexsdr.getiterator()

for element in iter:
    if element.tag:
        o=i+k
        xmlname=element.tag
    if element.keys():
        attributedict = dict(element.items())
        for name, value in element.items():
            krishna=element.items()
    if element.text:
        text = element.text

    xmlnamelist={"xmlname":xmlname,"text":text,"ownid":o,"parentid":o2,"xmlattkeys":{k:v for k,v in krishna}}

    xmlrss.append(xmlnamelist)

    if element.getchildren():
        o2=o
        for child in element:
            k=k+1
    i=i+1

rss.insert(xmlrss)
```

Error message i got in IDE as below when i apply krishna=dict(element.items()):

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    D:\test\mongo_rss.py    44      
    insert  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py 312     
InvalidDocument: key '{http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar}file' must not contain '.'
```

If krishna=element.items(),then in mongodb i am getting:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f69bb6e17ea930fd803a958"),
  "text" : "en-us",
  "xmlname" : "language",
  "xmlattkeys" : [["href", "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/xbrlrss.all.xml"], ["type", "application/rss+xml"], ["rel", "self"]],
  "parentid" : 2,
  "ownid" : 16
}
```

But i want

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4f69bb6e17ea930fd803a958"),
  "text" : "en-us",
  "xmlname" : "language",
  "xmlattkeys" : {"href":"http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/xbrlrss.all.xml", "type":"application/rss+xml", "rel":"self"},
  "parentid" : 2,
  "ownid" : 16
}
```

please help me in doing that.

Comment: What happens if you write: `for e in xmlrss: rss.insert(e)` at the end?

Comment: The problem remains same.... It shows problem with "." as i have mentioned in main post... . :(

Comment: I don't know. I read something about problems with bulk inserts so it was worth a try. You should add a printout of the contents of xmlrss to your code so we know what gets into the insert function.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
for name, value in element.items():
    krishna=element.items()
```

do

```
krishna = dict(element.items())
```

(And maybe consider using a more descriptive name for this variable.)

Comment: problem with "dict(element.items())" is when i run the program, it stops at the point where it shows key doesn't contain "."

Comment: +1. It's worth pointing out that the OP's code creates and re-creates `krishna` as many times as there are items in it...

Comment: it stop with error as  
"InvalidDocument: key '{http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar}file' must not contain '.'

Comment: @user1283171: Which line triggers this error message? I highly doubt, that `dict()` will complain about `.` in keys.

Comment: this is my XML
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/usgaap.rss.xml

and error message is
Message File Name Line Position 
Traceback    
    <module> D:\test\mongo_rss.py 52  
    insert C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py 310  
InvalidDocument: key '{http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar}file' must not contain '.'

Comment: @user1283171: that looks like a MongoDB error, so it's unrelated to your initial requirement.

Comment: @user1283171: Please add the error message to your question and give us line 52 (please mark it!) and surrounding from mongo_rss.py If you do not, then no one here will be able to help you since we do not see where the error is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
xmlnamelist={"xmlname":xmlname,"text":text,"xmlattkeys": {k:v for k,v in krishna}}
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Also, @larsman's solution is the way to go - create the correct data structure right away instead of transforming it to a list and back.

Comment: OK, then you don't have dictionary comprehensions. They were added in Python 3 and backported to Python 2.7. Why are you using an outdated version of Python?

Comment: I python2.7, the problem remains as it is. I have update my main post, please have a look on it.. .

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
 xmlnamelist={"xmlname":xmlname,"text":text,"xmlattkeys":dict(krishna)}
```

the special form (list of iterables) should allow it.
Some more corrections:

```
for element in iter:
    xmlname = element.tag if element.tag else ""
    attributedict = dict(element.items()) if element.keys() else {}
    text = element.text if element.text else ""
    xmlnamelist = {"xmlname"    :xmlname,
                   "text"       :text,
                   "xmlattkeys" :attributedict}
    xmlrss.append(xmlnamelist)
```

Note that you need to provide default values or you risk that the variables are not declared or filled with old (false) values.

Comment: problem with "dict(krishna)" is when i run the program, it stops at the point where it shows key doesn't contain "."

Comment: this is my XML sec.gov/Archives/edgar/usgaap.rss.xml and error message is Message File Name Line Position Traceback <module> D:\test\mongo_rss.py 52 insert C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py 310 InvalidDocument: key '{sec.gov/Archives/edgar}file' must not contain '.' – user1283171 11 secs ago

Comment: I have applied this solution too... but the problem remains same as i have mentioned in my main post.. :(

Comment: @user1283171: Maybe a bit late but let me mention that you should check the dictionary you put into the db. As the error message says you must not use '.' in the keys of this dictionary because of the structure mongodb is using for access to these elements. It seems that one url acccidently got to be a key.

Comment: you are right!!! My URL contains "." which is not allowed!!
anyway... i have converted them into list before inserting them!